# Get All records From Elastic Search without size

Tags: elasticsearch

My query is something like this :

```
{ "from": 0, "size": 100,"track_total_hits": true, "query": {"bool": {"filter": [{
     "bool": {
     "must_not": {
       "exists": {
         "field": "deleted_at"
       }
     }
    }}]}}, "sort": [{ "added_at"  : {"order" : "desc"}}]}
```

Now If I don't specify **size**  it gives only 10 records . And I don't know how many records are there . So what is possible thing to retrieve all data at once or even get count ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hits.total.value` will give you the value of the total number of documents, matching the search query.

**`track_total_hits` value defaults to 10,000. If the number of documents is more than 10,000, then the relationship will change to `gte`, instead of `eq`**

Refer to this official documentation, to know more about [`hits.total`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#hits-total-now-object-search-response)

```
"hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 11,             // note this
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": [
      {
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer , But I didn't get . In my case what I have to do ? can you please check my query I posted ?

Comment: sir How I will write my complete query with this ? I am confuse

Comment: @F128115 you don't need to change anything in your query. You can remove the `size` param from your search query and hit the query. In the response, you will get `hits.total.value` as shown in the response above.

Comment: @F128115 please hit the search query (which you gave in the question above), and let me know the value of `hits.total.value`. **This value will indicate the number of documents that matched your search query.**

Comment: @F128115 do you have any follow-up questions ?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch returns datas with size option. If you want to fetch all datas,
you should use pagination with [scroll api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html)

You can follow this [link](https://medium.com/@sourav.roy_4059/elasticsearch-pagination-by-scroll-api-68d36b8f4972)

Comment: thanks for answer,  I need all data once so this option seems not working

Comment: In elasticsearch you have two option for fetching data, first option via "size" second option is "scroll api". I understand you want to make query like in sql SELECT * but in elasticsearch as i said you can make only this two. With scroll api you can fetch all data in once.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of ES you are using? With ES 7.x count of matching documents will be present in the response under hits -> total -> value